# How to fix QMenu height when scroll enabled?

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, qmenu

I have a derived `MyQMenu` from `QMenu` and want to enable scrolling in case the menu expands too much.

This menu contains a lot of check boxes.

```cpp
class MyQMenu : public QMenu{
...
void customizeStyle(){
    QString menuStyle(
      "QMenu{"
      "menu-scrollable: 1;"
      "}"
    );
    this->setStyleSheet(menuStyle);
}
...
};
```

It does enable scrolling, but now, the menu height takes the entire screen height.

After some searching, I have tried:

- Reimplement `sizeHint()`, and give a fixed height (e.g. 600). The menu height is fixed, but the scroll bar disappeared, so I cannot scroll the menu.
- Customize `MyMenuStyle` from `QProxyStyle` to disable `QStyle::SH_Menu_FillScreenWithScroll`, but it does not work.
- Customize `MyMenuStyle` from `QProxyStyle` to disable `QStyle::SH_Menu_FillScreenWithScroll`, and set `QStyle::PM_MenuDesktopFrameWidth` to `100`, it works, but has a new problem: scroll bar disappeared when I clicked on one checkbox.

Is it possible to make `QMenu` scrollable, and with a fixed or proper height, instead of taking the entire screen height?